# Is there a difference between Core-os operator's and k8s custom controllers?

Tags: kubernetes, operators

Is there a difference between Core-os operator's and k8s custom controllers?
Are they both same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848258/kubernetes-controller-vs-kubernetes-operator   answer the question

Comment: Thanks got it. Will see link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Controller vs Kubernetes Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848258/kubernetes-controller-vs-kubernetes-operator)

Comment: Yes it does answer my question